# How to add color to a view in swift3?

Tags: ios

```
    let firstFrame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 240, width: 100, height: 150)
    let firstView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
    firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view.addSubview(firstView)

    let secondFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 50, height: 50)
    let secondView = UIView(frame: secondFrame)
    secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    view.addSubview(secondView)
```

This is the question the code above I'm having problem with changing the background color for view in swift3. The error that I get in the xcode compiler is, "cannot call value of non-function type 'UIColor'". Can anyone help me figure a solution to this problem. Is There a function that grabs a color for backgroundColor?

Comment: You can easily solve those errors yourself by ⌘-clicking on the symbol (e.g.  on `UIColor`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you working in Swift 3 it should be as below:

```
let firstFrame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 240, width: 100, height: 150)
let firstView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
view.addSubview(firstView)

let secondFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 50, height: 50)
let secondView = UIView(frame: secondFrame)
secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
view.addSubview(secondView)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
UIColor.blue
UIColor.green
```

Comment: it's working now. the error doesn't come up anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can just say things like

```
firstView.backgroundColor = .blue
```

No need to say "UIColor"; the compiler knows that the background color is a color. You just tell it *what* color.